# Can a smartphone acts as a power supply to a Model 1A?

Tags: power-supply, usb-power, pi-a

I have the following USB MicroB-to-A cable that I use for charging my phone (Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge):

[image]

I'm wondering if I can power my **Raspberry Pi 1 Model A** with my phone?!

The USB-MicroB end would plug into my phone, and the USB-A end would plug into my RPi. Would this work? Or would it "*fry my pi*"?

Comment: I looked at the voltage from my phone's power port. It's not 5V. At full charge I saw 4.2V. It's directly attached to the charge circuitry here. Make sure to verify your voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the model A supports back-powering through the USB port, you will bypass the fuses. So it is not a good idea in general.

BUT. As long as you do not connect other devices to GPIO and as your only USB port is occupied, you will hardly run into the situation that you route too much power through your Pi. So to my best knowledge your Pi will be save but potentially underpowered. Smartphones don't provide much power through USB OTG. My iPhone is limited to USB devices about 100mA (showing an alert stating a device draws to much power otherwise) which is WAAAY to low for a Pi. As the USB port on any smartphone is protected you will also be save on that side.

As I am confident that it will cause no damage to any of your devices I don't take responsibility. To my best knowledte your Pi will be underpowered and run unstable (potentially damaging the file system on the SD card).